# PythonでWebhockに対してデータを送りたい

Tags: python, python3, curl

Pythonでの計算結果をwebhockアドレスに対してpostしたのですが、うまくいきません。
下記がPythonのコードなのですが、何が間違っていますでしょうか？

`print(yatta)` は正常に表示されており、動作は問題無いのでは無いかと考えております。
CentOS7でpython3.6にはrequestモジュールがインストールされております。
特にエラーは出ていませんが、webhockされた先のteamsで受信が出来ておらず表示がされていません。

a4のファイルの中身は以下の様な値となっています。

```
1024
56360960
```

```
f = open('a4','r')
datalist = f.readlines()
print(datalist[0],end = '')
print(datalist[1],end = '')
print(type(datalist[0]))
print(type(datalist[1]))
s = int(datalist[0])
m = int(datalist[1])
print(s)
print(m)
print(type(s))
print(type(m))
f.close
yatta = (s*m*100)//(159.87*1024*1024*1024)
print(yatta)
if yatta > 20:
    import requests
    data = '{"text":yatta}'
    response = requests.post('https://abc.webhook.office.com/webhookb2/aaaaaa', data=data)    

else:

    pass
```

Comment: `data = '{"text":yatta}'` ですが、これは文字列になっていて、`requests.post` に渡す場合には辞書型の方が良いかと思います。`data = {"text": str(yatta)}`

Comment: data = {"text": str(yatta)} に書き換えて試しました。
data = {"text": dict(yatta)} の誤記かもしれない、と考えてこちらも試しましたが、共にtemasでは何も表示されない、という事象は変わりませんでした。

Comment: `response = requests.post(...` の直後に `print(response.text)` を挿入してレスポンスデータの中身を確認してみると何か分かるかもしれません。

Comment: Bad payload received by generic incoming webhook.
の内容が書かれていました。

Comment: [ここ](https://github.com/OfficeDev/outlook-dev-docs/issues/860#issuecomment-614709673)を読むと、`@context` や `@type` といったキーも必要な様です。